# Entity Framework Code First versus Guid

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

In my simple class I'm using data annotations to map properties to columns as such:

```
[Table("Member")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }

    // More properties go here
}
```

I can already write new members to my table but MemberId always defaults to a new Guid (0000-000-00...) instead of a beautiful server generated Guid.

I've seen scenarios where people change some setting called StoreGeneratedPattern in an EDMX file. But since I'm using Code First obviously I don't have this EDMX file...

So how would I go about solving this?

Any help is very much appreciated.

### UPDATE!!

Ok, just found the answer myself. You can use an annotation.

```
[Table("Member")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }

    // More properties go here
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using Guid as PK with EF4 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270721/using-guid-as-pk-with-ef4-code-first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an annotation:

```
[Table("Member")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }

    // More properties go here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been initializing my Guids in the class constructor since you don't need / can't use the auto-increment functionality that you use with int type keys.

So, I would change to...

```
[Table("Member")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MemberId (get; set;}

    public Member
    {
      MemberId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use this approach, how do you handle uniqueness of the Guid when saving changes to your context?